# Jquery code working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, animation

I have this piece of code that reveals a couple of divs when it is clicked and then they are hidden once another link is clicked. I'm trying to get this to show in Firefox and it may not be a problem in the js but all help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fadein').click(function(){
                    // Make the id overview show
                    $('#header-contact').hide('slow'); 
                    $('#header-portfolio').show('slow');
                    $('#content-portfolio').show('slow');
                    // override default a behavior
                    return false;
            });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fadein2').click(function(){
                    // Make the id overview show
                    $('#header-portfolio').hide('slow');                       
                    $('#header-contact').show('slow');
                    $('#content-portfolio').hide('slow');
                    // override default a behavior
                    return false;
            });
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fadein3').click(function(){
                    // Make the id overview show
                    $('#header-portfolio').hide('slow');                       
                    $('#header-contact').hide('slow');
                    $('#content-portfolio').hide('slow');
                    // override default a behavior
                    return false;
            });
    });
```

Comment: A link to test in Firefox would be helpful.  Have you tried using FireBug to test for Javascript errors?  Everything there looks ok.

Comment: Yeah, tried using Firebug and no errors showed up, would it be helpful to add all the code in my site? Then it may be possible to see if it were a problem I made with the CSS or HTML.

Comment: you are not closing the third script element, is that a typo? or the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try passing the `event` to each of the `click` handlers and before you `return false`, call `preventDefault()` on the passed-in `event` object.

example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fadeinX').click(function(e){
                // Make the id overview show
                $('#header-portfolio').hide('slow');                       
                $('#header-contact').hide('slow');
                $('#content-portfolio').hide('slow');
                // override default a behavior
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Web Developer by Chris Pederic](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) to clear the cache. I had exactly the same problem with Firefox and using the web developer to clear the cache solved it. Simple but you never know, and I had been pulling my hair out.

Comment: I downloaded the web developer but then I checked the problem on 2 other computers. All of them are running the script fine in both Chrome and IE (not sure about safari) but not in Firefox. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to `return false` at all if you `preventDefault();`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fadein').click(function(e){
     // Make the id overview show
     $('#header-portfolio').hide('slow');                       
     $('#header-contact').hide('slow');
     $('#content-portfolio').hide('slow');
     // override default a behavior
     e.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

Also move your JS into it's own file and only have one `$(document).ready(function() {...})` function and you can put all three of your events in there.