# Jquery not calling Webservice method in firefox browser and it is working good in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am calling webservice method from ajax jquery and it is working fine in Chrome and IE browsers and it is not working in Firefox.

**Jquery Code:**

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
   var objEmp = {
       employeeID:$("#EmployeeID").val(),
       employeeCode: $("#txtEmpCode").val(),
       employeeNotes: $("#txtupdatenote").val(),
       employeeAccessLevelID: $('#ddlupdateAccess').val()
   }
   var data = JSON.stringify({ objEmpUpdateRequest: objEmp });
   //alert(ajaxHelper('WebService.asmx/EmpUPDATE', data));

   ajaxHelper('WebService.asmx/EmpUPDATE', data).done(function (data) {
       var result = JSON.parse(data.d);          
       main[result.ObjResponse.responseMethod](result);
   }).fail(function (Header, TextStatus, ErrorMsg) {
       displayAlertMessage(TextStatus + ":" + ErrorMsg);
   });
});
```

If you check the code there is an alert

```
alert(ajaxHelper('WebService.asmx/EmpUPDATE', data));
```

when i uncomment this alert then it is working in Firefox also.

**I Reffered below links:**

[Jquery code working in Chrome but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003454/jquery-code-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox)

[JQuery UI working on chrome but not firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920655/jquery-ui-working-on-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Comment: do you mean '*you want to make an ajax request and detect if it success or fail*'?

Comment: No  by using the above method i am calling webservice method (EmpUPDATE).

Comment: the 'method' you meant is method of your `webservice.asmx`, isn't it? I was misunderstood, i thought this is the method of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this 'more-readable' script:

```
    $("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
       var objEmp = {
           employeeID:$("#EmployeeID").val(),
           employeeCode: $("#txtEmpCode").val(),
           employeeNotes: $("#txtupdatenote").val(),
           employeeAccessLevelID: $('#ddlupdateAccess').val()
       }
       var data = JSON.stringify({ objEmpUpdateRequest: objEmp });
       $.ajax({
            url     : "WebService.asmx/EmpUPDATE",
            data    : data,
            type    : "post",
            dataType: "json",
            cache   : false,
            success : function (result){
                alert("success\n"+result.toSource());
            },
            error   : function (a,b){
                alert(a.responseText+"\n"+a.statusText);
            }
       });
}
```

note: I don't know what will you do with this line:

```
main[result.ObjResponse.responseMethod](result);
```

Comment: That method will return response object to BL class.

Comment: yes. you can have it from `result` in `success` section of the above script. and the `result` is already formatted as JSON. if the return of your webservice is not json formatted, it will go to `error` section of the above script.